# Is it possible to get rid of a matrix in one side of an equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's say we have below equation:

$$ sA = B $$

Where $s$ is an scalar value and $A$ and $B$ are matrices. How can I find the value of s? If $A$ and $B$ were real numbers I could do

$$s = \frac{B}{A}$$

Comment: What is the $(i,j)$ entry on each side?

Comment: I am asking for the general case. Let's say A and B are nxn matrices.

Comment: If $A = B$, then $a_{ij} = b_{ij}$ for all $i,j$.

Comment: And I have told you the answer!

Comment: you mean $s = \frac{b_{ij}}{a_{ij}}$ ?

Comment: $B$ must be *exactly* $sA$ which means that for any $i,j$ must be $b_{ij}=s\cdot a_{ij}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that such an $s$ exists, it may be found by dividing an *entry* of $B$ by the corresponding entry of $A$, as both matrices must be the same size for the dimensions to match. Any entry of $B$ may be chosen for this, provided that the corresponding $A$ entry is not zero.